# Splitting blackslash-path using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm currently working on a jsp script that gets a path which I want split at the backslashes. Now my code doesn't seem to work. I think it's connected to the single backslashes in the path. The problem is I can't change them as the jsp will retrieve them from somewhere else...
Any suggestions what might be the reason?

```
<Property>

 <% String testsetPath = "..\test\subfolder\version\folder\folder2";
        String field = "testset";
        String container[] = testsetPath.split("\\\\");
        int sub = 0;

        if(field.equals("testset")){
            sub = 2;
        }
        else if (field.equals("testplan")){
            sub = 1;
        }

         String output = container[container.length - sub];
            %>

<availableValues>
    <value><%=  output%></value>
    <displayName>Test</displayName> 
    <description>Test</description>         
</availableValues>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because you have not escaped the slashes in "testsetPath"?

```
String testsetPath = "..\\test\\subfolder\\version\\folder\\folder2";
String container[] = testsetPath.split("\\");
```

If want this to work cross-platform, you might want to do...

```
String container[] = testsetPath.split(File.separator);
```

Comment: It is that's what I thought. But I have no influence on how I get the code is there a possibility to escape them in the code using `replace()` or something similar?

Comment: @Syo so do you mean the value of "testsetPath" comes from elsewhere? So in your code above, this is just set to an example value, right? If you have a string from elsewhere, you shouldn't need to do any "replace" calls, just call "split" with the escaped slash [ split("\\") ]